# Помогите разобраться, в чем ошибка в коде на Прологе?

Tags: prolog

**Задача**

> 1. Описать на Прологе базу знаний «Правители России», содержащую следующие факты:
>
>    - Ярослав Мудрый правил с 1019 по 1054 годы,
>    - Изяслав первый правил с 1054 по 1077 годы,
>    - Всеволод первый правил с 1078 по 1093 годы,
>    - Святополк  Второй правил с 1092 по 1112 годы,
>    - Владимир Мономах правил с 1113 по 1125 годы,
>    - Мстислав Великий правил с 1125 по 1132 годы.
> 2. Добавить к базе знаний «Правители России» правило, определяющее понятие «Великий князь в году Y», которое определяло бы имя правителя
>      России в произвольном году Y.
> 3. Добавить к базе знаний «Правители России» правило «Правили с года X по год Y», позволяющее вывести всех, кто правил Россией в период с
>      года X до года Y включительно.
> 4. Сформировать цели:
>
>    - Кто правил Россией с 1050 по 1080 годы?
>    - Кто был Великим князем в 1092 году?

**Решение**

```
predicates
  nondeterm pravil(string,integer,integer) /*name,beginn,end*/
  nondeterm pravitel(string,integer) /*name,year*/

clauses
  pravil(yaroslavmudryiy,1019,1054).
  pravil(izyaslavpervyiy,1054,1077).
  pravil(vsevolodpervyiy,1078,1093).
  pravil(svyatopolkvtoroy,1092,1112).
  pravil(vladimirmonomah,1113,1125).
  pravil(mstislavvelikiy,1125,1132).

  pravitel(X,Y):-pravil(X,A,B),Y>=A,Y=<B. 

goal
  pravitel(Y,1092), write(Y), nl.
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем ошибка в коде на Прологе (использую Visual Prolog v 5.2)?

> E;Test_Goal, pos: 398, 409 Syntax error

Comment: Очень нужно разобраться!

Comment: Никто не знает пролог!

Comment: а что за ошибка-то?

Comment: E;Test_Goal, pos: 398, 409 Syntax error

Comment: Всё, нашла и исправила ошибку сама. Всем спасибо.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, что у меня запустилось:

```
predicates
  nondeterm pravil(string,integer,integer) /*name,beginning,ending*/
  nondeterm pravitel(string,integer) /*name,year*/
  nondeterm praviteli(string,integer,integer)/*name,year,year*/
clauses
%Facts
  /* #1 Baza znanyi "Praviteli" */
  pravil(yaroslav_mudryiy,1019,1054).
  pravil(izyaslav_pervyiy,1054,1077).
  pravil(vsevolod_pervyiy,1078,1093).
  pravil(svyatopolk_vtoroy,1092,1112).
  pravil(vladimir_monomah,1113,1125).
  pravil(mstislav_velikiy,1125,1132).
%Rules
  /* #2 Velikiy knyaz v godu Y*/
  pravitel(X,Y):-pravil(X,A,B),Y>=A,Y<=B. 
  /* #3 Praviteli Rossii s goda X po god Y*/
  praviteli(P,X,Y):-pravil(P,A,B) , X<=A, X<=B,Y>=A, Y<=B. 
  praviteli(P,X,Y):-pravil(P,A,B) , X<=A, X<=B,Y>=A, Y>=B. 
  praviteli(P,X,Y):-pravil(P,A,B) , X>=A , Y>=B.
goal
/* #1 Kto pravil Rossiey s 1050 po 1080?*/
 praviteli(X,1050,1080), write(X), nl,

/* #2 Kto byil velikim knyazem v 1092 godu?*/ 
 pravitel(Y,1092), write(Y), nl.
```

Comment: добавь описание, что именно поменялось, по сравнению с кодом в вопросе

Answer (score -1):

Вроде вполне работает:

http://ideone.com/Yvh21k

```
pravil(yaroslavmudryiy,1019,1054).
pravil(izyaslavpervyiy,1054,1077).
pravil(vsevolodpervyiy,1078,1093).
pravil(svyatopolkvtoroy,1092,1112).
pravil(vladimirmonomah,1113,1125).
pravil(mstislavvelikiy,1125,1132).

pravitel(X,Y) :- pravil(X,A,B),Y>=A,Y=<B. 

solve(Y) :-
 pravitel(X,Y),
 write(X),
 nl,
 fail.
```

```
solve(1092).
```

Comment: В Visual Prolog v 5.2 выдает на это следующую ошибку: "E;Test_Goal, pos: 1, 3 Illegal keyword"

Comment: @Gadget, на ideone нет visual prolog'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну а зачем тогда давать не вполне правильные ответ?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а где _в вопросе_ сказано, какой пролог нужен? Какой нашёл, на том и дал.

Comment: @Gadget впредь пишите такие вещи прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Буду писать теперь сразу )

Comment: Мб кто-то знает, что не нравится Visual Prolog в коде из вопроса? Мне очень нужно в этом разобраться! Вроде бы же всё логично в нём, должен запускаться, но не хочет. Выдает такую ошибку: "E;Test_Goal, pos: 398, 409 Syntax error"

Comment: @Qwertiy, а ты перечитай вопрос. Там четко сказано, какой пролог используется.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, тобой 18 минут назад ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да. А за 19 часов до этого ТС ровно тоже написал(а) тебе в комментарии выше.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в комментарии к уже готовому ответу.